# Object to boolean conversion in Java

Tags: java

For example I have an array `Object[][] array = Object[n][2];`
Second row of this array contains an `boolean` data, due to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     boolean bool = true;
     array[i][1] = bool;
}
```

Is it possible to convert an `array[i][1]`, which is an object type, back to the `boolean` value?

Comment: Casts are your only bet, but why do you have a heterogeneous array to begin with?

Comment: you probably mean second column when you say [i][1]. Just wondering.

Comment: `System.out.println(((Object) true).getClass());`

Comment: @Makoto, I have used it to create JTable. And i just don't want to declare new class with Object and boolean attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a cast to convert it back to a boolean type. For example, if `array` is declared as an `Object[][]` but contains a `boolean` type, you can do this:

```
boolean bool = (Boolean) array[0][1];
```